# Syntax-highlighting for ##-comments in knitr not working as expected

Tags: syntax-highlighting, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I am using `knitr` and `RStudio`to create a report mainly consisting of `R` code. I want to use headers in the code to structure the text, example

```
## First part 
##############
```

When I `compile a notebook`to PDF then

```
# comment
```

is syntax-highlighted/ printed in the PDF in some textcolor for comments.

However, if I compile this to PDF, then

```
## comment
```

will *not* be syntax-highlighted. See the example:

[image: example]

I would like to have `##`type comments syntax-highlighted in PDFs. However, when I knit to HTML, `##`type comments are syntax-highlighted.

What am I missing here? How can I turn on syntax-highlighted for `##`comments in PDFs?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks,

Sebastian

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful, but are using RMarkdown or LaTex?  Second, are you adding comments in the style of # comment ####, by which I mean the initial hash symbol, your commented text, and four or more hash symbols on the same line?

Comment: Sounds like a bug of Pandoc's syntax highlighter.

Comment: seems like a bug in https://github.com/jgm/highlighting-kate, the library pandoc uses for syntax highlighting. feel free to submit a bug report there and mention it's for the `R` syntax highlighter.

Comment: @lawyeR: I am using Rmarkdown; I would like to have several hashes (#) at the beginning of a comment line for instance to indicate headlines in markdown style (e.g., "## header 2")

Comment: @mb21: ok, thanks, I will submit a bug report.